# Strange behavior of List in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, list, foreach

I work on winform project, when I need collect SpaceObjects in a List Spacesystem.
So, I created that List and one SpaceObject, down here.

```
List<SpaceObject> Spacesystem = new List<SpaceObject>();
SpaceObject objekt = new SpaceObject(3, 3, 5, 5, 5, "red");
```

Parametres of SpaceObjects are : positionx,positiony,weight,initialspeedx,initialspeedy,color

And this is in short, what my button "SaveObject" does, i write only lines related to it.

```
objekt.positionx=positionx;
objekt.positiony=positiony;
objekt.weight=double.Parse(textBox3.Text);
objekt.initialspeedx=double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
objekt.initialspeedy=double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
Spacesystem.Add(objekt);
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}", objekt.positionx, objekt.positiony, objekt.weight, objekt.initialspeedx, objekt.initialspeedy, objekt.color));
```

So, I saved for example two objects and after each save 
I gave MessageBox with right parametres.

Problem was, when i did

```
foreach (SpaceObject s in Spacesystem)
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}", s.positionx,s.positiony, s.weight, s.initialspeedx, s.initialspeedy, s.color));
```

Then, I had very strange results, both MessageBoxes were same. I tried it with more SpaceObjects before, but there were still same results in each MessageBox.
I dont know, how is it posibble, if you have some idea, please advice me.
Thank you very much,
Martin

Comment: My guess is that you've added a reference to the same object multiple times. Either that or you've got static fields. If you post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, we'll easily be able to tell. (WinForms is a red herring here - a short but complete console app will make it easier to see what's going on.)

Comment: How many "new" Spacesystem objects have you created?  Your code only shows one.  It looks like you keep updating the same 'objekt' object.

Comment: you guys beat me to it. It is hard to say without a more complete code listing, but you could make the program launch a function that creates a new object and assigns the values and adds it to the list. You are almost surely adding the same reference to the list each time.

Comment: Yes, I created only one object, and my Save button is at first updating the object and then add him to a List. Is it problem?

Comment: @MartinVlasák If you want to have a list that has a bunch of references to *a single object*, then no.  If you want to have a list that has references to different objects, then yes.

Comment: Ok, i get it. I did it, because i dont know the number of Spaceobjects the Spacesystem will have. Is there please any other way to get bunch of Spaceobjects to a spacesystem without knowing the number of spaceobjects before? Thanks.